# How to become an astonomer?

Tags: amateur-observing, observational-astronomy

I am very much interested in becoming an astronomer as a career. I know that my main focus should be in mathematics and science but; are there any specific degrees or competitive examinations I must obtain or attend, respectively? I am writing this question because I didn't obtain the desired answer.Please see my comment below for further information.

Comment: You mean to pursue it as a career, or as a hobby?

Comment: as a career....(sorry for answering late, my wi-fi stopped working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'd like to become an astronomer. What experience do I need?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/225/id-like-to-become-an-astronomer-what-experience-do-i-need)   also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21166/can-i-have-a-career-in-observational-astronomy-if-i-study-astrophysics-or-does-i?rq=1 , https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/660/what-study-profiles-could-land-me-the-job-of-astronomer?rq=1

Comment: Check the internet on different BSc and MSc programs. Most likely, you need to start as a physicist, and after you've got your BSc degree and quality well, then you can start an astronomer MSc course. The SE sites what could be useful for you 1. this, the Astronomy SE, 2. https://physics.stackexchange.com 3. https://academia.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Only saying that "the answers there are not enough" is not enough. So your question will remain held. Make your question more clear, and point to at least one essential point, what is not covered by the original question! Do it quickly, and if you are ready, ping me (write a reply comment starting with `@peterh`).

Comment: @peterh I understand your point but the other questions Rob Jeffries has mentioned are relevant and tell me the subjects I must focus on but they are telling the things I already know and not what I don't and need to know. Hence, I wrote a question of my own to get the desired answer which you gave.